# icepdf applet viewer blank

Tags: applet, viewer, icepdf

After searching for a while, I can't seem to find specific information on ICEPDF applet viewer issue I'm having. I successfully used ant build to build the dist folder, i signed the jar files, uploaded to my server. I can't figure out why I keep getting a blank screen, i tried using the  tags instead  tags but still getting a blank screen...... Thanks for your help.

```
    <body>
    <object width="800"height="600" archive="icepdf-core.jar, icepdf-viewer.jar, icepdf-applet.jar"
    <param name="type" value="application/x-java-applet;jpi-version=1.5.0"/>
<param name="java_arguments" value="-Xmx128m"/>
    <param name="classloader_cache" value="false"/>
    <param name="url" value="http://www.example.com/weekly.pdf"/>
    <param name="code" value="ViewerApplet.class"/>
</object>
</body>
```

Comment: *"http://www.example.com/weekly.pdf"*  Is this applet digitally signed?  Is the applet being served from example.com?  Does the applet swallow exceptions?  Is there any output in the Java Console?  Why an applet rather than a frame?

Comment: The applet is digitally signed. Its being served from www.ryansnotes.com/icepdf/dist/PDFApplet.html----Using an applet to control access to the document, users should only be able to print and not download.

Comment: *"users should only be able to print and not download."* Given a power user could pull up the page source, see the location of the PDF and download it directly, that will never be enforceable. BTW - that code you pasted is not valid.  It is not even well-formed.  Try [validating it](http://validator.w3.org/).

Comment: The code is not the problem, the code i've posted is just a snippet, The applet loads into the browser just fine. The problem is with implementing ice-pdf. I've tried using the object tag and applet tag, still getting a blank screen

Answer (score 0):

Verify first if the jar has been signed correcty by:

```
jarsigner -verify jar-file
```

If yes, try replacing the name of the jar, as sometimes the server saves a copy of the jar file, this is why sometimes changes done to the jar do not reflect when uploading to server.

Also, check if  java version of where the jar file is running is compatible to how the jar file was built.